# What is the dummy variable in the Henriksson-Merton model for market timing ability?

Tags: categorical-data, finance

I am a little confused about calculating the dummy variable on the Henriksson-Merton model for market timing ability.

Some researches used 1 if the excess return for market is negative but other researches used -1. How could I know the right one to use? Does any one know anything about Henriksson-Merton for market timing ability? I need it for my research

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the dummy variable should be $1$ if $R_m\geq R_f$, and otherwise it should be $0$, according to the original paper published by Roy D. Henriksson and Robert C. Merton themself.

But I can understand the logic that someone could use $1$ and $-1$ as the alternative value of dummy variable. Imagine, if the regression results shows the $\beta_2$ is significant while the dummy variable is $1$ or $-1$, that is to say, the mutual manager has the ability to minimize the total beta $(\beta_1+\beta_2 D)$ when $R_m<R_f$ and maximize the total beta when $R_m\geq R_f$.

This is amazing, right?  But I'm sure you can find the difficulty.

Getting $\beta_1+\beta_2$ when $R_m\geq R_f$ and $\beta_1-\beta_2$ when $R_m<R_f$ is almost an impossible job for any mutual manager.